# Crystal Reports Formula - Replacing Null value with Text

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, suppress

So, I'm much more familiar with Transact-SQL than I am with Crystal formulas.  What I would like to do is convert something like the following SQL where clause to be used in Crystal to conditionally suppress a section:
.
.
.
AND (osAddressUse.Description <> 'Conservator Address'
    OR (
        ISNULL(bcDocumentDetail.PrimaryStreet,'') = ISNULL(osaddress.PrimaryStreet,'')
        AND
        ISNULL(bcDocumentDetail.SecondaryStreet,'') = ISNULL(bcDocumentDetail.SecondaryStreet,'')
        )
        )
.
.
.

Basically, the section should only display if the osAddressUse.Description = "Conservator Address" OR both the Primary Street and Secondary Street within both tables bcDocumentDetail and osAddress are not identical.

What I came up with so far is the following, but it doesn't work 100% of the time:

{osAddressUse.Description} <> "Conservator Address"
OR
( {bcDocumentDetail.PrimaryStreet} = {osAddress.PrimaryStreet}
    AND 
{bcDocumentDetail.SecondaryStreet} = {osAddress.SecondaryStreet} )

There are some situations where the data in these fields can either be NULL or "".  If it's a NULL value, I want it converted to "", that way, they technically match, and the section will be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I was able to figure it out:

TRIM ({osAddressUse.Description}) <> "Conservator Address"
OR
(
    (IF ISNULL({osAddress.PrimaryStreet}) THEN "" ELSE {osAddress.PrimaryStreet})
        = (IF ISNULL({bcDocumentDetail.PrimaryStreet}) THEN "" ELSE {osAddress.PrimaryStreet})
    AND 
    (IF ISNULL({osAddress.SecondaryStreet}) THEN "" ELSE {osAddress.SecondaryStreet})
        = (IF ISNULL({bcDocumentDetail.SecondaryStreet}) THEN "" ELSE {osAddress.SecondaryStreet})
)